# Can I equate two parametrizations of the same surface?

Tags: surfaces, parametrization

This question arose to me when studying the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics), but it is really independent (there is no need to know about the method in order to answer my question).

Suppose I have a surface $\mathcal{S}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of which I know an explicit parametrization of the form

$$\Big\{ \big( x, y, z(x,y) \big) \, : x,y \in \mathbb{R} \Big\} = \mathcal{S} \, $$

(I know the function $z(x,y)$ ). Suppose I also know there exists another parametrization of the same surface, this time an implicit one, of the form

$$\Big\{ \big( t, \xi ( t,s) , \eta(t,s) \big) \, : t,s \in \mathbb{R} \Big\} = \mathcal{S} \, . $$

(I don't know the functions $\xi(t,s)$, $\eta(t,s)$ ). Am I allowed to identify these two parametrizations point by point? i.e. am I allowed to write

$$\big( x, y, z(x,y) \big) = \big( t, \xi ( t,s) , \eta(t,s) \big) \, ,$$

implying for instace that $x=t$? Or the only thing I know is that they both sweep the surface $\mathcal{S}$?

Answer (score 0):

The relation is

$z(x,y)=\eta(t,s)$ and $x=t$,$y=\xi(t,s)$

So

$z(t,\xi(t,s))=\eta(t,s)$

Comment: Okay but the problem I see is in the identification $y = \xi(t,s)$. Because $y$ is not supposed to depend on $x=t$, while $\xi$ does in general depend on $t$.